# Normality Test with different factors in Python

Tags: python, pandas, normal-distribution

I have a dataset with historical sales data, i'm trying to study if the sales of each SKU follows a normal distribution or not. For this, I'm using the shapiro wilk test (if there's a better option please let me know). Although I haven't been able to apply the formula for each different factor.

My csv data is in the following format

| SKU | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 12034 | 14 |
| 12033 | 24 |
| 12032 | 10 |
| 12034 | 8 |
| 12033 | 22 |
| 12033 | 12 |
| 12032 | 33 |
| 12033 | 15 |

I have 1600+ different SKUS ID's and the output im looking forward to get is a summary table.

| SKU | P-Value | Normal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12032 | 0.06 | Yes |
| 12033 | 0.12 | Yes |
| 12034 | 0.00 | No |

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
```

```
data = pd.read_csv('SalesHistorySample.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
p_value = stats.shapiro(df['Sales'].dropna())
```

I think I'm on the right track, although when I tried the groupby() function it didn't work out.

I'm actually new to Python, I appreciate any recommendation, material I can check and suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it. You can remove the `if len(g) > 3` if all of your SKU's have at least 3 records

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
def p_val(g):
    # significance level
    alpha = .05
    if len(g) >= 3:
        g['P-Value'] = scipy.stats.shapiro(g['Sales'].dropna())[1]

        if g['P-Value'].iloc[0] > alpha:
            # fail to reject
            g['Normal'] = True
        else:
            g['Normal'] = False
            
        return g[['SKU', 'P-Value', 'Normal']].iloc[0]

df.groupby('SKU').apply(p_val)
```

assuming `alpha = .05`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked more than fine.